# How to register ILogger in Azure Function Dependency Injection and make it work for other related solution

Tags: azure-functions, clean-architecture, ilogger

I am working on .NET CORE 6 Azure function App that have two functions of type HttpTrigger and TimeTrigger. I have another solution where I need to use logging too so I register logging in dependency Container of Azure Function Startup class.

I have issue that when I inject services, I don't get full login for example based on below code, Azure Function `Monitor` produced following stats and miss the log that I register in classes.

however if I pass the ILogger in Azure Function method then I get full log of information but then it throw null exception in another solution

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
```

[image]

`host.json`

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
 "applicationInsights": {
   "samplingSettings": {
     "isEnabled": true,
     "excludedTypes": "Request"
  }
},
"logLevel": {
  "default": "Information"
  }
 }
}
```

`Startup`

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
      builder.Services.AddLogging();
      builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
    }
}
```

`Azure Function`

```
public class HttpTestMessageAdaptor
{
    private readonly ILogger log;
    private readonly ITestMessageUseCase _testMessageUseCase;

    public HttpTestMessageAdaptor(ILogger<HttpTestMessageAdaptor> logger, ITestMessageUseCase messageUseCase)
    {
        this.log = logger;
        this._testMessageUseCase = messageUseCase;
    }

    [FunctionName("HttpTestMessageAdaptor")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
    {
        try
        {
            string name = req.Query["name"];

            var responseMessage = _testMessageUseCase.Process(name);

            Console.WriteLine($"AzureFunction: [Http-Trigger] [HttpTestMessageAdaptor] Executed At {DateTime.UtcNow}");

            log.LogInformation($"AzureFunction: [Http-Trigger] [HttpTestMessageAdaptor] [{responseMessage}] Executed At {DateTime.Now}");

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"Error: AzureFunction [Http-Trigger] [HttpTestMessageAdaptor] Executed At {DateTime.UtcNow}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

`Logging in class from another solution`

```
public class TestMessageUseCase : ITestMessageUseCase
{
    private readonly ILogger log;

    public TestMessageUseCase(ILogger<TestMessageUseCase> logger)
    {
        this.log = logger;  
    }

    public string Process(string name)
    {
        string responseMessage = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            log.LogInformation($"[UseCase] [TestMessageUseCase] Requested At Time [{DateTime.UtcNow}]");

            responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
               ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
               : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.LogError($"[Error] [UseCase] [TestMessageUseCase] At Dated [{DateTime.UtcNow} [{ex.Message}]");
        }

        return responseMessage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the azure monitoring logs for logging in the azure functions.

You can also use log4net and tracewriter for this.

Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp) for this.

Refer this [article](https://stackify.com/logging-azure-functions/) by Jared Nance on logging

Comment: Thanks for providing detail. also can I use serilog? for azure function project or not and if I can then is right choice?